# What is this an example of: "FOR SALE: Car by elderly lady with new body and spare tire"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Historical examples:

> - Croesus asked the oracle what would happen if he
>     attacked Persia. The reply: ‘A mighty empire will be humbled’.
> - Thank you so much for the book. I shall lose no time in reading it.

Modern example:

> I am opposed to taxes which slow economic growth.

Humorous:

> The anthropologists went to a remote area and took photographs of some native women, but they weren't developed.

What is the term used for these examples?

Comment: You might want to change the title into a question which summarises what you're asking.

Comment: @Steve, actually the title is a nice example and a very intriguing one.

Comment: You can tune a piano, but you can't tuna fish

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7338/books-and-other-things-with-the-same-name/7340#7340

Comment: I have an entire book of these taken from newspapers at home, titled "Red Tape Holds Up Bridge"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are examples of [amphibology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphibology). To quote its Wikipedia entry:

> Amphibology or amphiboly (from the
>   Greek ἀμφιβολία, amphibolia) is an
>   ambiguous grammatical structure in a
>   sentence.

Comment: Much as I love amphibology, I think it has to be deliberate.

Comment: @malvolio I think it *has* to be deliberate too, how else could those clever amphibologies appear!   (Amphibologizing your comment, if it wasn't already, deliberately.)

Answer (score 9):

These are examples of *syntactic ambiguity*. They demonstrate ambiguity between alternate syntactic structures underlying a sentence.

- The man saw the boy with the binoculars.
- They are hunting dogs.
- Free whales.
- Police help dog bite victim.
- He saw that gas can explode.
- We saw her duck.
- The kiwi eats roots and leaves.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_linguistic_example_sentences for this and other types of lexical ambiguity.

Comment: In some cases the ambiguity is syntactic, but in other cases it's semantic or even pragmatic. For example, "A mighty empire will be humbled" is definitely not a sentence whose syntax is ambiguous, and I'm not sure whether its semantics are ambiguous either. It's the context that makes it ambiguous. Pragmatic ambiguity: http://linguistlessons.blogspot.com/2011/01/pragmatic-ambiguity.html

Comment: I knew a man with a wooden leg named Smith...

Comment: Ewe are on the write path

Comment: @Ilya Kogan: Yes, I didn't quite notice, but the examples in the question body are not the same as the one in the headline. But the page I linked to covers all kinds of ambiguity.

Comment: I thought it was the Panda, which [eats, shoots and leaves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eats,_Shoots_%26_Leaves)

Answer (score 4):

This is a classic example of a misplaced modifier.

Answer (score 4):

The sentence in your title contains a classical figure of speech commonly called **zeugma** (your other sentences are rather double entendre or simply ambiguous, as the others have mentioned).
See Wikipedia on [zeugma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma) and [syllepsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma#Syllepsis); what Wikipedia calls *syllepsis* is usually simply called *zeugma*, as syllepsis is the most common significant application of zeugma in rhetoric and literature.

> **Zeugma** (from the Greek: ζεῦγμα,
> zeûgma, meaning "yoke") is a figure
> of speech describing the joining of
> two or more parts of a sentence with a
> single common verb or noun. A zeugma
> employs both ellipsis, the omission of
> words which are easily understood, and
> parallelism, the balance of several
> words or phrases. The result is a
> series of similar phrases joined or
> yoked together by a common and implied
> noun or verb.
>
> ...
>
> **Syllepsis**, also known as *semantic
> zeugma*, is a particular type of zeugma
> in which the clauses disagree in
> either meaning or grammar. The
> governing word may change meaning with
> respect to the other words it
> modifies. This creates a semantic
> incongruity that is often humorous.
> Alternatively, a syllepsis may contain
> a governing word or phrase that does
> not agree grammatically with one or
> more of its distributed terms. This is
> an intentional construction in which
> rules of grammar are bent for
> stylistic effect.

See my answer to a similar question here: [Books and other things with the same name](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7338/books-and-other-things-with-the-same-name/7340#7340) .

Answer (score 3):

Those are examples of double entendres.

Comment: A double entendre is usually reserved for double meanings where the other meaning is sexual.

Comment: @Henry: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double%2Bentendre) mentions "usually risqué" for definition 2 and "ambiguity of meaning arising from language that lends itself to more than one interpretation" as definition 1.

Comment: @nmichaels: I'm not entirely clear what definition 1 there is supposed to cover that definition 2 doesn't (the OED says only "A double meaning; a word or phrase having a double sense, esp. as used to convey an indelicate meaning," and the MW learner's dictionary linked to from there only seems to include the second).  Regardless, in actual usage, one of the interpretations of a "double entendre" is usually, as the OED so British-ly puts it, "indelicate."

Comment: @henry It seems that you are implying that the selected examples are not as racy as I thought?  My mind must be in the gutter -- I was sure they were doubles entendres.

Comment: @nmichaels "Adianoeta" is sometimes suggested as synonym for "double entendre" .  I think this supports your view on the flexibility of "double entendre" .

Comment: @jgbelacqua: Some of the examples (the one in the title, for instance) certainly qualify, but if the one about Croesus attacking Persia is racy, it's certainly going over my head.

Answer (score 1):

While previous answers have correctly described the technical names for the ambiguity contained in these statements, I believe that they represent an inherent ambiguity and lack of structure in modern English that is less present in other languages.

For example, my son eats "Organic Baby Rice".  Is this rice made of organic babies?  Similarly how is a "bamboo cage" different to a "bird cage"?  One implies a cage constructed of it's modifier, another the intended prisoner. For comparison, French distinguishes between "riz de bébé" and "riz pour bébé".  While these examples are trivial, I believe they illustrate the point.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be a "dangling participle?"  The famous one in medicine is "Studies on monkeys using endoscopes," but then someone remarked that there is always a monkey at the end of an endoscope.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a [Garden Path sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence)

Comment: [Paraprosdokian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraprosdokian) is a sentence that __semantically__ leads one way but then unexpectedly turns another. A garden path sentence does so _syntactically_. Most of the OPs examples have two distinct meanings and not two distinct parsings.

Comment: I'm not upvoting it because it doesn't seem to be the correct answer, but thanks for the term!

Answer (score 0):

Those are examples of dangling modifiers. A dangling modifier causes ambiguity in a sentence because the object to which a modifier refers is unclear.