# Is there a single word for speech with a double meaning?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, antanaclasis

How could one put, in a single word, language that has multiple meanings at once?

Comment: Related: [Alternative to “double entendre”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17042/alternative-to-double-entendre)

Answer (score 13):

There's also [polysemous](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/polysemous) or [polysemantic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/polysemantic), both of which mean "having many meanings."

Comment: +1.  This seems to be the clearest term for what the questioner requests — it doesn’t have the extraneous connotations that some others have (humour in the case of *pun*, deliberate deceit or evasiveness in the case of *equivocation*), and it also covers all examples, unlike *homonym*, *homophone*, etc., which are each rather more restrictive.

Comment: Actually, we may need something like *bi-/disemous* or *ambisimous*.

Answer (score 3):

A **pun**:

> The pun, also called *paronomasia*, is a form of word play which suggests two or more meanings, by exploiting multiple meanings of words, or of similar-sounding words, for an intended humorous or rhetorical effect.

<sup>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun)</sup>

Perhaps more specifically a *homonymic* pun, which relies on words that are both *homographs* (same spelling, different meaning) and *homophones* (sound alike), e.g., "Being in politics is just like playing golf:

> . . . you are trapped in one bad *lie* after another."

Comment: +1 Paronomasia is exactly the *pun*-itive measure I had in mind.

Comment: Pun seems to imply humorous plays on words. Is there a word extending to all?

Comment: Here's another link to http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/P/paronomasia.htm

Answer (score 1):

Equivocation could work.

> Equivocation is classified as both a formal and informal logical fallacy. It is the misleading use of a term with more than one meaning or sense (by glossing over which meaning is intended at a particular time). It generally occurs with polysemic words.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivocation)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for :

> Equivocation

There is also:

> Double Entendre

Answer (score 1):

**ambiguity**  (or ambiguous) and its associated figure of speech **amphiboly** capture the "multiple meanings at once". Both can apply to a single word or to an entire phrase or sentence.

Comment: I think this is the best, because it is not confined to words. A sentence might be ambiguous despite none of its words being so. For example, *The boy saw the man with the telescope* can mean either that the man had the telescope, and the boy saw him; alternatively, it can mean that the boy, by means of the telescope, saw the man. Both meanings arise from the same set of words, without changing the meanings of the words. It is how the words combine which determines which meaning ultimately arises.

Answer (score 0):

*Bisemous*.

It really means "with two meanings".

Answer (score -2):

you do it [ostensibly](http://www.wordnik.com/words/ostensibly/)

> "So maybe there’s a legal convention
>   concerning how definitions such as
>   this are to be
>   circumscribed/overridden/whatever by
>   the common English meaning however
>   vague by comparison of the term
>   ostensibly being defined?" *— The
>   Volokh Conspiracy » **Hate Crimes and
>   Double Jeopardy:***

I just realized that if your word has at least two meanings at the same time that you might be referring to something [ironic](http://www.wordnik.com/words/ironic)

> ```
> –adjective
> Both coincidental and contradictory in a humorous or
> poignant and extremely improbable way.
> ```
>
> *It is ironic that Einstein, who was
>   such a revolutionary young man, was
>   reduced to irrational denial of
>   quantum mechanics in his later years.*

Comment: Is this a joke? If not, “ostensibly” here means as much as “allegedly”. As in, “it’s *claimed* that this term … is being defined (but it really isn’t)”.

Comment: @Konrad the question was "How could one put, in a single word, language that has multiple meanings at once?" How would you do it? I'd do it ... ostensibly :)

Comment: @pageman: 'ostensibly' does imply that there is an alternative meaning, but it is primarily about the situation rather than the word or language.

Comment: @Mitch the question was how "does one" do it, right? ;)

Comment: @pageman: that is a subtle reading of the intention of the OP that the OP probably didn't intend. 'Ostensible' is about a surface meaning, but on reflection there is another meaning (It is not about the process of -inducing- the multiple meanings , the act of constructing the utterance with more than one meaning (which is what I think you're getting at). In that case it would be __prevaricating__, __equivocating__, or __dissembling__, with the added connotation of 'with the intent to deceive' (which 'ostensible' doesn't have).

Comment: @Mitch your examples require too much premeditation - many time we just want to be "merely" ironic - in that sense we can say we are being "ostensible" & in irony - we convey at least two meanings at the same time (the face value meaning & the ironic one)