# Tom admires Martha as a politician. Who is a politician?

Tags: grammar

'Tom admires Martha as a politician.'

Can this sentence have two interpretations?

1. Tom is a politician and admires Martha.
2. Tom admires Martha because she is a politician.

Does the interpretation change when we move the pharse 'as a politian' to the beginning of a sentence?

As a politician Tom admires Martha.

Comment: Of course it's ambiguous. Why bother asking such a question.

Comment: I'm wondering which interpretation is the most common.

Comment: Without a *specific* context the text is ambiguous. And that *context* is nothing to do with language - we're really just being invited to speculate on whether politicians are more likely to ***admire** other people*, or to ***be admired by** other people*.

Comment: Dude! If you know the sentence is ambiguous, bothering about what is the most common way it will be read is silly. Don't write it that way!

Comment: The question is important as regards the comparison of two languages. The lack of inflection results in ambiguity. I wanted to make sure if it is like that for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this an example of: "FOR SALE: Car by elderly lady with new body and spare tire"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15139/what-is-this-an-example-of-for-sale-car-by-elderly-lady-with-new-body-and-spa) [@Robusto:] 'These are examples of **syntactic ambiguity**. They demonstrate ambiguity between alternate syntactic structures underlying a sentence.

_The man saw the boy with the binoculars_. / 
_They are hunting dogs._ ...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It means that Tom admires Martha's quality as politician. Similarly 'Tom admires Martha as a mother' is not ambiguous (unless Tom is short for Thomasina).

If you put the "as a politician" at the front of the sentence then it does, indeed, reverse the meaning. In that case we are saying that Tom, in his capacity as a polititcian, admires Martha generally.

This becomes clearer if we have two descriptions such as:

> Tom, as a politician, admires Martha as an activist.

or

> As a politician Tom admires Martha as an activist

There is no ambiguity in this, Tom is a politician and Martha is an activist. Each descriptive phrase relates to the noun closest to it.