# What is this wordplay I'm thinking of involving homonyms?

Tags: single-word-requests

I remember knowing there was a name for this type of sentence construction, but I can't recall it and google is failing me.

The basic concept is that you use a word in two different meanings in the same sentence. A (poor) example is: "He ran a marathon and his own company", playing on the idea of running as a physical activity versus running a company. What is that called?

Comment: [Joe Stockley was in an expensive sports car and deep trouble. This time, he had really let his mouth and his exotic foreign lover run away with him and it was getting beyond a joke and his immediate circle of friends in the form of rumours and speculation. As he ran a red light, the conversation back in his mind and away from his troubles, he couldn’t help but feel a sense of rising panic and the soft matte finish of his hand-stitched leather steering wheel.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/2829/300)

Comment: @RegDwighт And that would be where I first heard the term: on WriteBadlyWell. I couldn't remember that either, to go look it up. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Of the difference between zeugma and syllepsis](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23592/of-the-difference-between-zeugma-and-syllepsis)

Comment: Language Log gives this phenomenon an amusing name: *WTF coordination*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Zeugma](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/zeugma?q=zeugma) Is the word you're looking for:

> a figure of speech in which a word applies to two others in different senses (e.g. John and his driving licence expired last week).

Also know as [syllepsis](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/syllepsis).

Comment: Syllepsis is the term I was thinking of! Thanks bunches. Now I also know a more accurate term :)

Comment: [Of the difference between zeugma and syllepsis](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23592/of-the-difference-between-zeugma-and-syllepsis).

Comment: +1 It's also a specialized form of *double entendre*.

Answer (score 0):

Another version of wordplay using homonyms is chiasmus--the figure of speech in which two or more clauses are related to each other through a reversal of structures in order to make a larger point.  (Thank you Wikipedia, for this definition)  Example:
"Never let a kiss fool you, or a fool kiss you."

Comment: This is good information but doesn't really answer the question. It would probably be better as a comment.